# A bound for $\log\ n>3k\log\log n $.

Tags: analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $k$ is natural number. I want to find the best bound for
$\log\ n>3k\log\log n $.

That is, if we have $n>A$ then $\log\ n>3k\log\log n$, where $A$ is term according to $k$.

Comment: Apply the exponential to $\log(n)>3k\log(\log (n))$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde what is $A$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde this bound is false. Because $A$ have term according to $n$

Comment: If $k > 0$, then you can take any $x\in(1,e)$: Then we have $\ln x\in(0,1) > 0$ and $\ln \ln x \in(-\infty,0) < 0$. Thus $\ln x > k\ln\ln x$ for all $k>0$ and $x\in(1,e)$.  Notice the condition on $x$ is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts $n$ and $k$ is $>0$! Indeed $k$ fixed.

Comment: @Amirali Fatehizadeh: Oops, I wrote $x$ instead of $n$.  Just take $n\in(1,e)$. For example $n=2$ and the inequality will be satisfied for any $k>0$. Assuming with $\log$ you mean Natural logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln n/\ln\ln n$ is an increasing function for $n > e^e$. So the bound $A$ will satisfy $\ln A = 3k\ln\ln A$ and $A > e^e$. Let $\alpha = \ln\ln A$. Then we have
$$
e^\alpha = 3k \alpha\Longrightarrow -\alpha e^{-\alpha} = -\frac{1}{3k}\Longrightarrow \alpha = -W_{-1}\left(-
\frac{1}{3k}\right),
$$
where $W_{-1}$ is a branch Lambert $W$ function, defined implicitly by $W_{-1}(z)\exp W_{-1}(z) = z$ and $-W_{-1}(z) > e$ for $-1 <z < 0$. This gives
$$
A = \exp\exp\left[-W_{-1}\left(-
\frac{1}{3k}\right)\right] = \exp\left[-3kW_{-1}\left(-
\frac{1}{3k}\right)\right] = \left[-3kW_{-1}\left(-
\frac{1}{3k}\right)\right]^{3k}
$$
Now, for $z$ close to zero, $W_{-1}(-z)\sim -\ln(z)$. So for large $k$, we have $A\sim[3k\ln(3k)]^{3k}$. This extraordinarly fast growth shows just how slowly $\ln n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: For $k=3$, What is the value of $A$?

Comment: @AmiraliFatehizadeh About $25\cdot10^{12}$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks you.